# Emacs24 won't download marmalade-repo.org archive

Tags: emacs, package, elisp, emacs24

Installed emacs-snapshot from [this](http://emacs.naquadah.org/) debian repo. Added in my init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

When I M-x package-refresh-contents it hangs for about 2 minutes with the message:

```
Contacting host: marmalade-repo.org:80
```

Then times-out with the message:

```
Failed to download `marmalade' archive.
```

As I can see with tcpdump, package lists *are* actually fetched. Unsure why the error occurs. Tried installing the package.el provided at the Marmalade page, no luck.

Comment: Don't know if this might also be a repository problem but at this time the 'Next' button at the bottom of http://marmalade-repo.org/packages links to a javascript function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Marmalade archive is back up now.